# Trying seque data from UIViewController to Weather API

Tags: ios, swift, weather-api

I am trying to pass data from a UIViewController to a SecondViewController that is getting data from a WeatherAPI.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var raceTextField: UITextField!


let races = ["Melbourne", "Bahrain", "Shanghai", "Baku",
             "Barcelona", "Monaco", "Montreal","Le Castellet","Speilberg",
             "Silverstone","Hockenheimring","Budapest","Spa-Francorchamps","Monza","Singapore","Sochi","Suzuka","Austin","Interlagos","Abu Dhabi"]
var selectedRace: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    createRacesPicker()
    createToolbar()
}


@IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "getWeather", sender: self)
}

func createRacesPicker() {
    let racePicker = UIPickerView()
    racePicker.delegate = self
    raceTextField.inputView = racePicker
}
func createToolbar() {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    raceTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
@objc func dismissKeyboard(){
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}
 //MARK: - UIPickerView Delegate extension
 /***************************************************************/
//UIPickerView here
 extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
   }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: 
Int) -> Int {
    return races.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return races[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectedRace = races[row]
    raceTextField.text = selectedRace
}
//Write the PrepareForSegue Method here
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getWeather" {
        let weatherVC = segue.destination as! WeatherViewController

        weatherVC.city = raceTextField.text!
       }
     }
   }
```

Now what I want to do is update this screen with weather data.  Below is my code to update the weatherData.
So basically segue the city chosend from the view controller to the WeatherViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class WeatherViewController: UIViewController {

//constants
let weatherDataModel = WeatherDataModel()

var city = ""

@IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherIcon: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!

let WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
let APP_ID = "8a99df7bf7ef4a4a202732c392b2d240"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cityLabel.text = city
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//MARK: - Networking
/***************************************************************/

//Write the getWeatherData method here:
func getWeatherData(url: String, parameters: [String : String]) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Success we got the weather data!")
            let weatherJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.updateWeatherData(json: weatherJSON)

        } else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            //self because of the closure.  Therefore you have to specify the function.
            self.cityLabel.text = "Connection Issues"
        }

    }
}

//MARK: - JSON Parsing
/***************************************************************/
//updateweatherdata method here

func updateWeatherData(json: JSON) {
    if let tempResult = json["main"]["temp"].double {
        weatherDataModel.temperature = Int(tempResult - 273)
        weatherDataModel.city = json["name"].stringValue
        weatherDataModel.condition = json["weather"][0]["id"].intValue
        weatherDataModel.weatherIconName = weatherDataModel.updateWeathericon(condition: weatherDataModel.condition)
        userEnteredNewCityName(city: city)
        updateUIWithWeatherData()
    } else {
        cityLabel.text = "No data available"
    }

}

func userEnteredNewCityName(city: String){
    let params : [String : String] = ["q" : city, "appid" : APP_ID]
    getWeatherData(url: WEATHER_URL, parameters: params)
}

 //Write the updateUIWithWeatherData method here:


func updateUIWithWeatherData() {
    cityLabel.text = weatherDataModel.city
    temperatureLabel.text = String(weatherDataModel.temperature)
    weatherIcon.image = UIImage()
  }

 }
```

The weatherDataModel is in a seperate class.  So I am trying to add MVC into the app.
I can't seem to see what I am missing.  It's probably something really simple.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added string named city in WeatherViewController ?

Comment: Did you try saving the string raceTextField.text in a string variable before segueing to the weather view controller. And then passing that string to weatherVC.city  in prepare for segue method..

Comment: Having a look now.  I used a UIPickerView to select the city.

Comment: This is what I have added as the string in the WeatherViewController. ```var city = ""```

Comment: Is it because city is an empty string?

Comment: How are the three methods related to the workflow in the controller? Where is `userEnteredNewCityName` called? Where is `updateWeatherData` called? What is `getWeatherData`? And you are encouraged to use `Decodable`. Any third-party library like SwiftyJSON has become obsolete.

Comment: Where is it added ?? Is it in view controller life cycle method or variable initialization??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the method to load the data in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cityLabel.text = city
    userEnteredNewCityName(city: city)
}
```

and delete the line

```
userEnteredNewCityName(city: city)
```

in `updateWeatherData` otherwise you'll run into an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks Vadian  that was really helpful.  Now the imageView is not showing but I will try and figure that out later.